# What does "active" mean in my flagging summary page?

Tags: support, flag-history

My flagging summary page displays "active" for a particular flag that seems to be not actioned yet. What does that mean?

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMEse.png]

Comment: Oh, I see fancy new features coming to us.

Comment: Guess it means the flag is still waiting to be reviewed by a moderator... :)

Comment: +1 - I was wondering what active means..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All flags that appear in a user's flagging summary that are not yet dismissed by a moderator have this marking on them.  It appears to mean "awaiting attention by a moderator."

Comment: What if one is flag-hellbanned?

Comment: What's a flag hell ban?

Comment: Where your flag weight gets so low that your flags don't get handled. Since your flags don't get handled, you can't increase your flag weight. Since you can't increase your flag weight, your flags don't get handled...

Comment: I don't get to see flag weights, so I can't speak to that.

Comment: @Undo Flag weight doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @Doorknob: It does, it's just not displayed anymore.

Comment: @Robert I thought I recalled a comment from Jeff saying something along the lines of "if I dropped that column from the database right now, nothing would change"

Comment: @Doorknob I believe it is used on the backend to help order flags in the mod queue.

Comment: @Undo Yes, but I thought I remember that it was removed. I'm trying to find the post that said that...

Comment: Technically, the column still exists - but it is no longer used anywhere. @Doorknob.

Comment: I suspect my flag weight is poor, so there's not much point in flagging anything then hey?

Comment: @Shog9: In other words, there's no such thing as a flag hellban.

Comment: Correct, @Robert - we have a replacement planned (with more banning, less hell), but not yet implemented. FWIW, very few people (even people who were extremely bad at flagging) ever managed to hit 0 flag weight - under 400 on Stack Overflow. It was... Nearly useless in practice.

Comment: What is the point of "active" flags? If it isnt helpful/declined, then a flag obviously hasn't been handled.

Comment: And why the word "active"? Why not a word more representative of the state, like "pending"?

Comment: I tend to agree, "active" is insufficiently descriptive - we should call it, "waiting on @animuson"...

Comment: to active flagger like me, "active" indicator feels convenient. Eg yesterday I had 14 flags waiting for response (at Programmers), it was fairly difficult to track the status of these

Comment: I have a flag marked "active" which has been "active" for 15 days.  Is that really active?

Comment: @demongolem: Yes.  I dismissed it.